Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\ell^\infty$ vs product $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$
Is it the case that every Borel subset of $\ell^\infty$ belongs to the product $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, and if not, does anyone know a counter-example?
(In other words, this question but with $\ell^\infty$ instead of $\ell^2$.)

There are $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ Borel subsets of $\ell^\infty$ while the product $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$, so the answer is no.

Thank you! Do you have a counter-example by any chance?

Any non-Borel subset of ${0, 1}^\mathbb{N}$ works. Any subset of ${0, 1}^\mathbb{N}$ is closed (and thus Borel) in $\ell^\infty$.

Great, thank you!
